# setting ports for container in docker for docker golang api

Tags: docker, go, docker-api

I am looking forward to do something below like this using docker golang api

cmd : docker run -t -i -p 8989:8080 "image-name" /bin/bash

Also I am using golang sdk https://github.com/moby/moby/client or https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client and my docker api version is 1.30 (Client & Server both)

Here is the piece of code I am using

```
 package main

 import (
       "fmt"

       "github.com/docker/docker/client"
       "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
       "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
       "golang.org/x/net/context"
       "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat"
    //"github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat"
)

func check(err error) {
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
}


func main(){
    ctx := context.Background()
cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
check(err)


config := &container.Config{
Image : image-name,
ExposedPorts: nat.PortSet{
    "8080/tcp": struct{}{},
},
Cmd : [] string {"sh","-c","while true; do sleep always; done","/bin/bash"},
}

host_config := &container.HostConfig{
     PortBindings: nat.PortMap{
     "8080/tcp": []nat.PortBinding{
         {
             HostIP: "0.0.0.0",
             HostPort: "8989",
         },
      },
   },
}


  resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx,config,host_config, nil,"")
  check(err)


  if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); 
      err != nil {
        panic(err)
  }


}
```

After Compiling this code I get the following error

```
# command-line-arguments
src\main\createcontainer1.go:53: cannot use "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet literal (type "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet in field value

src\main\createcontainer1.go:65: cannot use "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap literal (type "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortMap in field value
```

If somebody knows what could be the problem and how to fix it.
Please answer to it as I am beginner with docker.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Golang issue with how `vendor/` works.

Remove the nested vendor directory:

```
rm -rf vendor/github.com/docker/docker/vendor
```

If you are using `glide`, you should use `glide install -v` when installing the dependency.

For more details, check this reported [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28269)

Comment: I am not using glide. Is there anyway without it? I can't find the vendor directory like mentioned above...the directory in my system is C:\Projects\Go\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\docker\docker\vendor\github.com\docker and the directory has go-connections folder in it.Suggestion please..

Comment: Actually, `docker` use vendoring. Can you try to delete the `vendor` directory ? - the error references to it - `cannot use "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet literal (type "github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet) as type "github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/nat".PortSet in field value`

Comment: I deleted the vendor directory and I ended up getting errors below 
src\github.com\docker\docker\pkg\system\syscall_windows.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\github.com\Sirupsen\logrus (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Projects\Go\src\github.com\Sirupsen\logrus (from $GOPATH)
src\github.com\docker\docker\client\container_commit.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/docker/distribution/reference" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\github.com\docker\distribution\reference (from $GOROOT)
   and similar more like this and please guide me to fix it.

Comment: Sorry... :( You can restore the `vendor` directory from `https://github.com/moby/moby/vendor` (moby is the new repository for docker), or probably from your clone copy. How did you install this docker package firstplace ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein I have the exact same issue and I installed the packages via "go get -u "

Answer (score -1):

My solution for OSX:

```
mv /Users/<user>/go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/github.com/docker/go-connections/{nat,nat.old}
```

Comment: You need more explanation for how this solves their problem.